# JMS Delivery Failure - Error Destination on WebLogic Server

Tags: jms, weblogic12c

Aftering putting a message on a error queue how can I redelivery this message to the original queue?

Do I need to create a MDB to take this message from the error queue and put on the original queue or weblogic has some configuration?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far

Comment: I've create two queues, one to receive the original message and another to receive error messages. On the original queue I've configured at "Error Destination" the error queue to put messages when messages can not be delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve this:

- Move messages back manually using WebLogic Administration console
- WLST/Java code that uses moveMessages method from
  [JMSMessageManagementRuntimeMBean](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/wls/WLAPI/weblogic/management/runtime/JMSMessageManagementRuntimeMBean.html) interface
- You could configure Redelivery Delay Override and Redelivery Limit on queue level so  WebLogic would retry few times before moving failed message to error destination